# Pause and resume downloading with pycurl

Tags: python, download, pycurl

I'm writing a code to download files using `pycurl`. So I want to know that is there a possibility to pause my download and then resume it from wherever it's been paused?
Does `pycurl` support these features or is there any other library which support pause and resume?

Answer (score 4):

```
import os
import pycurl
import sys


def progress(total, existing, upload_t, upload_d):
    existing = existing + os.path.getsize(filename)
    try:
        frac = float(existing)/float(total)
    except:
        frac = 0
    sys.stdout.write("\r%s %3i%%" % ("File downloaded - ", frac*100))

url = raw_input('Enter URL to download folder/file: ')
filename = url.split("/")[-1].strip()


def test(debug_type, debug_msg):
    print "debug(%d): %s" % (debug_type, debug_msg)

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.FOLLOWLOCATION, 1)
c.setopt(pycurl.MAXREDIRS, 5)

# Setup writing
if os.path.exists(filename):
    f = open(filename, "ab")
    c.setopt(pycurl.RESUME_FROM, os.path.getsize(filename))
else:
    f = open(filename, "wb")

c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEDATA, f)

#c.setopt(pycurl.VERBOSE, 1) 
c.setopt(pycurl.DEBUGFUNCTION, test)
c.setopt(pycurl.NOPROGRESS, 0)
c.setopt(pycurl.PROGRESSFUNCTION, progress)
try:
    c.perform()
except:
    pass
```

Possible to download file for example - *.tar, .dmg, ,exe, jpg etc .

Used pycurl for resume download.

Testing of this code as:

- Run this file on terminal like:

Here is the log on terminal,

```
anupam@anupampc:~/Documents$ python resume_download.py 

Enter URL to download folder/file: http://nightly.openerp.com/6.0/6.0/openerp-allinone-setup-6.0-20110625-r3451.exe 

File downloaded - 199%
```

If you stop this download by pressing Ctrl + C and starts process to download file/folder , it start from where it was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

If you stop the thread and close the connection, you can use HTTP Content-Range to continue your request where you left off.   Just find out how many bytes you have already, and use RESUME_FROM to start from there:

```
import pycurl

starting_point = 999 # calculate this

url="http://test-url"
curl = pycurl.Curl()
curl.setopt(curl.URL, url)
curl.setopt(curl.RESUME_FROM, starting_point)
curl.perform()
curl.close()
```