# Disconnecting the connection in pycurl

Tags: python, connection, pycurl

I'm writing a python code to download files using `pycurl`. 
Is there any possibility to inform my program to disconnect the connection?
I mean that while the code is running, I want to disconnect the connection whenever I want.
(e.g. by clicking on a button and invoking a function). It can be used to pause the download.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775892/pause-and-resume-downloading-with-pycurl

Comment: Thank you, but as you see it's about resuming the connection. I want a way to disconnect using `pycurl`.

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes. To answer your question's easier part, the solution's to perform a "malicious" `return` statement in your `pycurl.WRITE_FUNCTION`.

An example here in my [project](https://github.com/woozyking/tidehunter) demonstrates how to actually disconnect a theoretically never-ending HTTP GET request (streaming)

```
def _on_data_receive(self, data):
    self.buffer += data

    if data.endswith('\r\n'):  # or any valid chunk delimiter
        # Do something about self.buffer
        print self.buffer

    if True:  # some valid condition to disconnect
        return -1  # the way to stop the stream, would raise pycurl.error
```

Answer (score 1):

- Yes, you could use callbacks see those examples from [PyCurl Doc](http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/doc/)
- A lot of C examples from libcurl are very helpful [LibCurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/example.html)
  *you easily can use those options in python*